# Python flask application - javascript can't access newly added select option

Tags: javascript, python, flask, sqlalchemy, jinja2

I've spent a while trying to work this out but can't understand what I'm missing.

I'm launching a Bootstrap 5 modal from a link on an HTML (jinja) template.  The template contains a select field containing a list of addresses.  The modal captures a new address and, on save, when the modal closes, I can successfully get the new address appended to the list of options in the select field.

Yet when I try to use Javascript to set the field to the new address, it leaves the field as blank.  I'm trying to do this by trying to add the option with the highest value (i.e. the length of the options list).

**HTML**

```
<!-- Select field -->
<div class="col-sm-7 w-auto">
    {{ wtf.form_field(form.individual_birth_location, class='form-select w-auto') }}
</div>

<!-- Link to trigger modal -->
<div class="col-sm-2 w-auto align-self-end mb-0">
    <a class="link-success" href="" id="birth_location" data-bs-toggle="modal" 
data-bs-target="#addlocation">
Add new location</a>


<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="addlocation" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="addLocationLabel"
     aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title" id="addLocationLabel">Add location</h5>
                <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal"
                        aria-label="Close"></button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <input type="hidden" name="type" id="type" value=""/>
                <div class="container-fluid">
                    <div class="form">
                        <div class="row mb-3">
                            <!-- Various field to capture parts of the address -->
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary"
                        data-bs-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id = "btnaddlocation" 
value="Add" name="addlocation"/>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

My Bootstrap select field has options with values and text, e.g.

```
<option value="14">London, United Kingdom</option>
```

**Javascript (at the bottom of this HTML template):**

Note that I use the eventType variable to capture which of these links the user clicks (there are a couple on the page) which use the same modal.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var eventType = "";
    var birthlocation = document.getElementById('individual_birth_location');
    var len = birthlocation.length;

    document.getElementById('birth_location').onclick = function() {
    eventType = "birth"
    }

    document.getElementById('btnaddlocation').onclick = function() {
    if (eventType === 'birth') {
        birthlocation.value = len;
    }

</script>
```

**What have I tried**

Aside from searching SO and various other forums: -

- Printed out the value of len (the number of options in the select field) - this outputs the correct number of options including the new one
- Set birthlocation.value to a hardcoded value e.g. `birthlocation.value = "1"` - this works fine and shows option number 1.
- Set birthlocation.value to a value of the penultimate option e.g. `birthlocation.value = len-1`, this selects the option with a value of one less than the length of the options in the select field and the relevant option shows up.
- Setting `birthlocation.value = len` doesn't have any effect, the field stays blank
- If I type `birthlocation.value = len` into the console directly, the newly added address appears as I want it to.

Why can't my javascript access the last added option?  It's like the script has to fully execute before I have access to it.

Many thanks for any help.